# How can I setup a standalone techdocs documentation?

Tags: mkdocs, backstage, techdocs

I just setup a local backstage instance with `create-app` and the first thing I'm trying to do is create a standalone techdocs component, for a "getting started" type of docs.

In the [backstage docs](https://backstage.io/docs/features/techdocs/creating-and-publishing#use-the-documentation-template), it says:

> Your Backstage instance should by default have a documentation template added. If not, copy the catalog locations from the create-app template to add the documentation template.

Unfortunately, the standard setup created by create-app doesn't seem to include the docs template, just a Node.js example. And the catalog locations in the create-app template also don't have it.

I tried setting it up manually - this is my folder structure. I created the catalog folder in the same folder where all the backstage files are:

```
backstage/
    catalog/
        techdocs/
            docs/
                index.md
            catalog-info.yaml
            mkdocs.yml
    app-config.yaml
    // the rest of the backstage files
```

catalog-info.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: backstage.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: "getting-started-docs"
  backstage.io/techdocs-ref: dir:.
spec:
  type: documentation
  lifecycle: experimental
```

mkdocs.yml:

```yaml
site_name: "getting-started-docs"
site_description: "How to get started with this portal"
```

app-config.yaml (the relevant parts, the rest is the default stuff `create-app` generated):

```yaml
techdocs:
  builder: 'local'
  generator:
    runIn: 'docker'
  publisher:
    type: 'local'
locations:
    - type: file
      target: ../../catalog/techdocs/catalog-info.yaml
```

I see the component in the software catalog, but on the detail page the "View Techdocs" button isn't working and the "Docs" page also says it has "No documents to show". I didn't change any of the techdocs configuration in app-config.yaml.

When I run `yarn dev` I see the following relevant logs, which don't sound good:

```
[1] 2023-12-08T09:41:21.994Z search info Collating documents for techdocs via DefaultTechDocsCollatorFactory type=plugin documentType=techdocs
[1] 2023-12-08T09:41:22.079Z backstage info ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023:09:41:22 +0000] "GET /api/catalog/entities?filter=metadata.annotations.backstage.io%2Ftechdocs-ref&offset=0&limit=500 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)" type=incomingRequest
[1] 2023-12-08T09:41:22.085Z search warn Index for techdocs was not created: indexer received 0 documents type=plugin documentType=techdocs
[1] 2023-12-08T09:41:22.086Z search info Collating documents for techdocs succeeded type=plugin documentType=techdocs
```

I also tried running `npx @techdocs/cli serve --verbose` but it fails with:

```
verbose: [docker/mkdocs] ERROR    -  Config value 'docs_dir': The path 'docs' isn't an existing directory.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here? What do I need to do to get a standalone techdocs documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The clue was in the startup logs:

```
"GET /api/catalog/entities?filter=metadata.annotations.backstage.io%2Ftechdocs-ref&offset=0&limit=500 HTTP/1.1" 200
search warn Index for techdocs was not created: indexer received 0 documents type=plugin documentType=techdocs
```

I tried the GET request against `http://localhost:7007/api/catalog/entities?filter=metadata.annotations.backstage.io%2Ftechdocs-ref&offset=0&limit=500` and there really were no results, which gave me the clue that something is wrong with the `backstage.io/techdocs-ref` annotation. The [docs for the techdocs-ref annotation](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/well-known-annotations#backstageiotechdocs-ref) show that the structure should have been:

```yaml
metadata:
  name: "getting-started-docs"
  annotations:
    backstage.io/techdocs-ref: dir:.
```

I also updated the [backstage docs](https://backstage.io/docs/features/techdocs/creating-and-publishing#create-a-standalone-documentation) with a little guide.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).